# Will the data redownloaded from firebase database if I am using keepSynced and setPersistenceEnabled true

Tags: android, firebase, asynchronous, caching, firebase-realtime-database

If I used keepSynced and made it true and setPersistenceEnabled and set it true in my app when a listener asks for a data will it download it again from the database after the app restarts or it will be reused from the cache? and when will this data removed from the cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data will be returned from cache for queries where the data from the server is unchanged since it was saved in the cache.

The data will be removed from cache when the cache exceeds 10 MB and the data hasn't been used recently.  (I believe it's an LRU cache.)

Comment: If the data changed in the database will it downloads only the new data from the database and return data for the query from the cache or it will re download all the query data from the database